# Unable to change file's mime type

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, httpwebrequest, mime-types

I'm trying to change the mime type of a file as described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) to `"application/vnd.google-apps.folder"`. However when I make the web request no error is thrown but the mime type does not change.

This is my code:

```cs
public string MimeType
{
    get
    {
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonMetadata); //the json of the fileID
        return data.mimeType;
    }
    set
    {
        RandomMethods.CreateRequest( //custom method for creating HttpWebRequest
            "PATCH", //method
            string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{0}?access_token={1}", FileID, Auth.AccessToken), //url
            "application/json", //content type
            "{ \"mimeType\": \"" + value + "\"}" //body
        ).GetResponse().Dispose();
    }
}
```

`get` is working correctly while `set` is not. This confuses me as my `Name` variable works correctly and with completely the same method only with the names swapped out.

This is the `CreateRequest` method I used:

```cs
public static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string method, string url, string contentType, string body)
{
    var req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.Method = method;
    req.ContentType = contentType;
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    req.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    return req;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are trying to change a file's mime to a Folder's mime type (**application/vnd.google-apps.folder**), that's not feasible, what you can do instead if you want to change a Google Drive file mime type like for example **application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet** or **application/vnd.google-apps.document**, you can use the [***Files: export***](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) endpoint.

[image]

Passing as parameters the document id and the mimeType you want to change it, you will get as a response that same document, but in the desired mimeType.

For further knowledge in all the mime types available, check [G Suite documents and corresponding export MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats).